Thumbnail generation using golang+ffmpeg
I try to generate thumbnail from video mp4 using Golang+ffmpeg.
Let me provide some steps:

Tried to generate using terminal ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -vframes 1 thumbnail.jpg - all works successfully
Tried to generate from golang and put result into stdout    cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", "test.mp4", "-ss", "00:00:00", "-vframes", "1", "-f", "image2pipe", "-") - all works successfully
Trying to open video using os.ReadFile and bytes.NewReader and after that -    cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", "pipe:", "-ss", "00:00:00", "-vframes", "1", "-f", "image2pipe", "-") And in this step I have an error.
Below provided all code and na error

    r, err := os.ReadFile("test.mp4")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to read video file: %v", err)
    }
    
    videoBuffer := bytes.NewReader(r)

    cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", "pipe:", "-ss", "00:00:00", "-vframes", "1", "-f", "image2pipe", "-")

    cmd.Stdin = videoBuffer

    // Capture output as bytes
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out

    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr

    // Run the command
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("ffmpeg command failed: %v, stderr: %s", err, stderr.String())
    }

    // Convert bytes to image.Image
    img, _, err := image.Decode(&out)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to decode thumbnail: %v", err)
    }

Error
2024/04/23 13:25:51 ffmpeg command failed: exit status 183, stderr: ffmpeg version 7.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/7.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenvino --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x136504080] stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x136504080] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 3496 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.26.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 3496 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x136504080] stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file
[in#0/mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x600001134000] Error during demuxing: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input 0:0 after EOF
[vf#0:0 @ 0x600001f2c000] Task finished with error code: -1094995529 (Invalid data found when processing input)
[vf#0:0 @ 0x600001f2c000] Terminating thread with return code -1094995529 (Invalid data found when processing input)
[vost#0:0/mjpeg @ 0x104a04650] Could not open encoder before EOF
[vost#0:0/mjpeg @ 0x104a04650] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vost#0:0/mjpeg @ 0x104a04650] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
[out#0/image2pipe @ 0x60000182c000] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
Conversion failed!

Also tried to do something like this  cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-analyzeduration", "10000M", "-probesize", "10000M", "-i", "pipe:", "-ss", "00:00:00", "-vframes", "1", "-f", "image2pipe", "-") - and had the same error (almost the same).
How to fix code or ffmpeg command - to bring this code workable?

I don't know about the go but this is how I do it at terminal. ffmpeg -ss HH:MM:SS -i video.mp4 -f image2 -vframes 1 image.jpg

Yeh, it works for me, but here you use video by name video.mp4, how to work with video as bytes array (for example using cat video.mp4 |)?

When piping to ffmpeg, I have to use -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -i - it seems to be picky about color space, so match the stream to the -pixel_format.  You may just need the -i - for pipe to stdin.
